# Product measure of Lebesgue and counting measure on discrete and usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, product-measure

$\textbf{Corollary}$: Let $X,Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be regular Borel measures on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. If $E$ is a Borel subset of $X\times Y$ that is included in a rectangle whose sides are Borel sets that are $\sigma$-finite under $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively, then

a) the functions $x\rightarrow \nu(E_x)$ and $y\rightarrow \mu(E^y)$ are Borel measurable, and

b) $(\mu\times \nu)(E)=\int_X\nu(E_x)\mu(dx)=\int_Y\mu(E^y)\nu(dy)$

The problem I am trying to solve:

Show that the corollary fails if $E$ is an arbitrary Borel subset (or even closed) subset of $X\times Y$. More precisely, show that part (a) can fail and that part (b) can fail even (a) holds. As a hint, let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and Lebesgue measure and let $Y$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology and counting measure.

I read the definition of discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$, which according to my understanding would be the collection of all singletons and arbitrary unions and intersections of them (which already challenges the fact that $\nu$ is supposed to be regular, since the hint suggests to consider the counting measure, but let's ignore this for a moment). I have not fully grasped what discrete topology means. Then, the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the one formed by open intervals.

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure (I will use $\lambda$ instead of $\mu$), and $\nu$ be the counting measure.

Then let $E=V\times \emptyset$, where $V$ is Vitali's set. Since $\nu(\emptyset)=0$, $E$ is a Borel subset of $X\times Y$ but $y\rightarrow \lambda(E^y)=\lambda(V)$ would not be Borel measurable. For $x\rightarrow \nu(E_x)$, I would try to use a similar argument/idea.

I don't really  know how to show that (b) can fail even if (a) holds.

So, I would appreciate if someone 1) can help me clarify what discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ means, 2) can tell whether my approach to prove that part is valid, and 3) can give me a hint on to show that (b) can fail even if (a) holds.

Comment: The discrete topology is the one where **all** subsets are open (and closed).

Comment: Yes, that's what I read. But the usual topology is the collection of all open intervals, then is the usual topology contained in the discrete topology?

Comment: **Every** topology on a set is contained in the discrete topology.

Comment: Then the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ would just the power set? and in general, the discrete topology on a set would just be the power set of that set?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok. So in my case, the discrete topology with the counting measure would be always $\infty$ except at the singletons, right?

Comment: The counting measure satisfies $\mu(A)=|A|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other answers on this website that pretty much answer my question. I'll add them here in case someone needs them in the future.

[This does not answer directly but gives insight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874295/product-of-lebesgue-and-counting-measures), [This one is very comprehensive, it helped a lot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70888/uniqueness-of-product-measure-non-sigma-finite-case?noredirect=1&lq=1), [This one is quick to read](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262900/lebesgue-vs-counting-measure-on-0-1?rq=1).